# Not Found: /media/media/photos/e.jpg in django

Tags: django

I've deployed a project on a web server. In my project everything is working fine but I'm unable to print an image on the profile page. On my local environment everything is working fine but on the deployed version I'm getting the following error: Not Found: /media/media/photos/e.jpg in django.

models.py

```
class Matr(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/photos/', null=True, 
            blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
MIDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

profile.html

```
{% if user.matr.photo %}
    <img src="{{ user.matr.photo.url }}" width="330">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: When do you get the error, when you upload or when you try to load the profile page?

Comment: Can you remove the if statement in your urls.py. You are not allowed to run with debug turned on in production so the urlpatterns will probably not be updated in this case.

Comment: uploading fine it will uploaded successfully .image unable to displaying on profile page

Comment: i removed if statement error showing invalid syntax.

Comment: image stored in database at the time of signup on profile page only not displaying..in our system displaying on profile but in server not displaying

Comment: First of all you should not be serving your media files with django on production, use your web server for that (nginx or apache). All your media files are put inside the MEDIA_ROOT directory so you should configure nginx to fetch anything from location `MEDIA_URL` (/media/) from `MEDIA_ROOT`. Second, in your template, you should prepend the MEDIA_URL to your `url`: `src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{user.matr.photo.url}}` because urls of uploaded media are always **relative** to `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

models.py

```
class Matr(models.Model):
     photo = models.ImageField()
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
     import debug_toolbar
     urlpatterns += [path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))]
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

profile.html

```
<img src="{{ user.matr.photo.url }}">
```

And make sure that after uploading photo, you have that photo in 'media_root' library.

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem

check the import in urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```